# Does Libxslt support mutable arguments?

Tags: xslt, libxslt

In our company, we are moving from MSXML 6.0 engine to Libxslt.

Our XSLT code contains a lot of flags, counters and arrays implemented in JS, which MSXML supported and Libxslt does not.

As a replacement, I am looking for some sort of mutable arguments support. Does Libxslt have one? Something along the line of saxon:assignable functionality

I know that that is against the "natural" language design, but I am dealing with a large body of flawed code that would be very difficult to re-write...

Comment: Stop kicking the can down the road and move to Saxon now.  If the free version doesn't suit, surely the paid version is less expensive than the dev time required to migrate and maintain code against a vastly inferior library.

Comment: You can find out which extensions are supported by calling `xsltproc --dumpextensions` from the command line. Funnily enough, *some* Saxon extensions are supported - but `saxon:assign` is not among them. If you're up to it, you could try writing your own (see: http://www.xmlsoft.org/xslt/extensions.html) but I believe your time would be better spent fixing your XSLT code - whether for libsxlt or for a more modern processor.

Comment: We actually tried to move to Saxon but apparently, there are some compatibility issues between our product and specifically Saxon...

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the extensions ill check it out